# Number Slider with number visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have this demo : https://fiddle.jshell.net/preetisingh/3eeecd88/

Currently I am using radio buttons to select the number. I want to use a slider instead of radio button. Similar like Jquery range slider. But the problem is the bar is not getting hidden. I have also checked the mobile slider controls:http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_forms_slider

But I am not able to implement. As you can see in the demo instead of selecting radio button i want to scroll the over the number as well i want the click on the numbers and store the selected values in local storage. Can anyone tell me how to implement this??

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_forms_slider

in above demo you can use `$(".ui-slider-handle").attr("aria-valuetext")` to get sliders value.

Comment: and you can also store value like "localStorage.test=$(".ui-slider-handle").attr("aria-valuetext")"

Comment: Is it possible to scroll the yellow color background over the radio buttons??

Comment: I mean the swipe gesture